# Stop subsystem in simulink

Tags: simulink

I have a question regarding simulink subsystems. I have one big model and one small model in one file (so as a complete memory system). The small model takes data from the big model and performs some function and when it is stable I have to stop the small model from working. How is this possible in simulink? I have tried with stop simulation command, but it stops the whole simulation.

Answer (score 5):

In Simulink terminology, you have one model, with two subsystems in it.  To *turn off* any part of a model you need to place it (i.e. the part you want to turn off) in an Enabled Subsystem, and make the enable signal false.